# Efficient way to generate random combinations of parameters with index as a hash function

Tags: python, cartesian-product

I have 13 variables with step sizes 15, which means each variable has a length of 15 `np.linspace(min, max, step)`. If I try to get all the combinations, that would be around 15**13 combinations. I want to take 10,000 samples from this combination space, i.e., `np.random, choice(15**13, 10000, replace=False)`. This will generate indexes of the combinations I am interested in. Now how to generate these combinations? Below is the code to generate brute-force combinations:

```
def _build_combinations(self):
    #val_dict = {'A': [50, 100], 'B': [10, 40], ...}
    val_dict = {k: np.linspace(*v, self.n_steps) for k, v in val_dict.items()}
    
    for instance in itertools.product(*val_dict.values()):
        yield dict(zip(val_dict.keys(), instance))

for i, param_dict in enumerate(self._build_combinations(), 1):
            self.write(i, param_dict)
```

Here, `i` is the unique index of that combination. It works for a small number of steps. But for large steps, even the `np.random.choice` throws memory error.

My questions are:

1. how to generate 10,000 random indexes from 13**15 numbers without running into memory error.
2. given the indexes, how to generate the corresponding combinations without running `itertools.product`.

Comment: Generating random combinations is easy, do you definitely also need the indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools


def _build_combinations(val_dict):
    for instance in itertools.product(*val_dict.values()):
        yield dict(zip(val_dict.keys(), instance))


def params_to_index(val_dict, param_dict):
    result = 0
    for key, values in val_dict.items():
        result *= len(values)
        result += values.index(param_dict[key])
    return result


def index_to_params(val_dict, i):
    param_dict = {}
    for key, values in list(val_dict.items())[::-1]:
        i, v_index = divmod(i, len(values))
        param_dict[key] = values[v_index]
    return param_dict


def test_index():
    val_dict = dict(
        a=[1, 2],
        b=[3, 4, 5],
        c=[6, 7, 8, 9]
    )
    for i, param_dict in enumerate(_build_combinations(val_dict)):
        assert i == params_to_index(val_dict, param_dict)
        assert param_dict == index_to_params(val_dict, i)


test_index()
```

Comment: Thanks! `params_to_index` and `index_to_params` is what I needed